# Prolog dict predicate matching

Tags: prolog, predicates

Given this program, why am I forced to define every atom in the predicate, even if they're anonymous.  Why is it that undefined variables in a dict predicate aren't thought of as anonymous?

```
funt2(X) :-
    X = point{x:5, y:6}.

evalfunt(point{x:5, y : 6}) :-
    write('hello world!').

evalfunt(point{x:_, y : _} ) :-
    write('GoodBye world!').
```

Why can't I just say

```
evalfunt(point{x:5}) :-
        write('GoodBye world!').
```

^that won't match, by the way.

I may as well just use a structure if I have to define every possible value in the dict to use dicts.

What's the motivation here?  Can I do something to make my predicate terse?  I'm trying to define a dict with 30 variables and this is a huge roadblock.  It's going to increase my program size by a magnitude if I'm forced to define each variables (anonymous or not).

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question, but I think the main problem here is the understanding, that `dict` is just a complex data type, like tuple, which has data AND structure. If you have, for example two facts `fact(point{x:5, y:6}).` and `fact(point{x:5}).`, then the query `fact(point{x:_}).` will match the second one, but not the first one. And the query   `fact(point{x:_, y:_}).` will match the first one, but not the second.

Comment: The issue is having to define every field in the dict to define a matching predicate.  Why is this?  If all you care about is the value of X being 5, why must you write y: _ ... + EVERY other member in the dict

Comment: Because if you don't write them, it will potentially match dict's with different structure.

Comment: If you want a shortcut, you can always define a rule that will do it for you

Comment: Could you post an example?  I was having trouble doing this without once again defining the dict.  I'm a bit new to prolog.  I'll accept an example of that as it will probably be terse enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by doing the following

```
checkiffive(Y) :- 
        get_dict(x, Y, V), V=5.
```

You need to use the built in methods for unifying values from a dict.

Described in chapter 5.4 of the SWI prolog reference

http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/devel/doc/SWI-Prolog-7.1.16.pdf

Comment: See the update to my answer. In SWI-Prolog 7 a new mechanism available

Answer (score 4):

Dict is just a complex data type, like tuple, which has data AND structure. If you have, for example two facts:

```
fact(point{x:5, y:6}).
fact(point{x:5}).
```

Then the query

```
fact(point{x:_}).
```

will match the second one, but not the first one. 
And the query

```
fact(point{x:_, y:_}).
```

Will match the first one, but not the second.

Now, if you want to match facts of the form `fact(point{x:_, y:_, z:_})` only by one specific field, you can always write a helper rule:

```
matchByX(X, P) :- fact(P), P=point{x:X, y:_, z:_}.
```

So having facts:

```
fact(point{x:5, y:6, z:1}).
fact(point{x:1, y:2, z:3}).
fact(point{x:2, y:65, z:4}).
```

and quering

```
matchByX(1, P).
```

will return:

```
P = point{x:1, y:2, z:3}
```

**UPDATE:** 
 
Moreover, in SWI-Prolog 7 version the field names can be matched as well, so it can be written in much more generic way, even for facts with different structures:

```
fact(point{x:5, y:6, z:1}).
fact(point{x:1, y:2}).
fact(point{x:2}).
fact(point{x:2, y:2}).

matchByField(F, X, P) :- fact(P), P.F = X.
```

So query:

```
?- matchByField(x, 2, P).
P = point{x:2} ;
P = point{x:2, y:2}.
```